# Retrieve status for a list of FedEx tracking numbers

Tags: vba, excel

**Background**

If you buy something from our facility, you will get a box with a shipping label on it. The two main numbers it will have are a **FedEx tracking number** and a **carton number**. For cartons that are not already in a manifested or invoiced status within our warehouse management system, it is necessary to check the FedEx website to determine if a carton has left our building. The statuses that I would be looking for on the FedEx website are "picked up", "in-transit", and "delivered".

The FedEx website categorizes tracking numbers in various sections depending on status. In June 2019, while looking at the html elements, there were 19 sections. To clarify, if you have a list of numbers you're looking up, the website takes the tracking numbers out of order, so as you're comparing your list with the website, you're scrolling up and down constantly trying to figure out which section the number is in. In most of my usage, there were only 2-3 sections used, but it still required constant up and down comparing back and forth. 
Ok, so you have the status on the website, you match that 10+ digit long tracking number with the one on your list, then you can highlight the associated carton number. The carton number that is in-transit is what we need, so we can process the carton number.

Another issue is the FedEx website only allows you to paste in 30 tracking numbers at time. So, if you're doing this manually for 1000 tracking numbers, you must somehow break up your list into 30 chunks at a time, then paste them into the website, do your looking back and forth comparing exercise, then do that 33 more times. That is going to take a long time, and due to nature of the process and length of the numbers, it will be very error-prone. You might even give up, because it’s so tedious.

**Objective**

I had a column of FedEx tracking numbers. In another column, I had a list of the associated carton numbers. My goal was to have a third column show the FedEx status. On that third column, I applied conditional formatting of green fill color to highlight text containing “picked up", "in-transit", "delivered". I could then filter on the green color, and I would have a list of carton numbers that had left the building. That was the end of my coding. From there, I could take that list and paste it into our warehouse management system to do the necessary processing.

**Short walkthrough:**

Start off on shData (1.User Input) by pasting in the tracking & carton numbers like so:[image: 1. User Input]

The code will generate links where each link concatenates up to 30 tracking numbers together, like so:[image: 2. Links]

The code will loop through the links, opening up Internet Explorer, Ctrl+A (selecting all), and Ctrl+C (copy), then return to shPastes(3. Pastes) and paste the results. Some filtering will occur, as to not grab all the unnecessary text.

Finally, in shStatus (4. Status), the filtered pastes will form into a table, and an index match will show the associated carton. A green filter on the status column will only show cartons in-transit, like so:[image: 4. Status]

**A few notes**

This is my first time posting. I've been programming in VBA for less than a year. I'm a beginner. I don't know how to do arrays. Error handling is new for me. I have RubberDuck installed. This code is actually a re-write of my original, which was awful code, but it worked and saved me a ton of time at work.

I could have used XMLHTTPRequests to grab element id's, but there were too many possible status sections to mess around with, and if the site changed at all, the code might stop working.

I'm looking for a critique, so I can improve further. Thanks for your time.

**Code Explorer:**
[image: Code Explorer]

**Worksheet Codename**: `shData`

```
'@Folder("FedEx_Tracking")
Option Explicit

'@Ignore ProcedureNotUsed
Private Sub StartTrackingButton_Click()
    If DoSimpleChecks = "Not Ready" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ProgressIndicatorForm.Show

End Sub

Private Function DoSimpleChecks() As String

    DoSimpleChecks = vbNullString
    '//Check if data has been pasted
    With shData
        If .Range("A2").Value = vbNullString Or .Range("B2").Value = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "Please paste in the following data:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "TRACKING number into A2" & vbNewLine & "CARTON number into B2", vbInformation, "Required Data"
            .Activate
            .Range("A2").Select
            DoSimpleChecks = "Not Ready"
        Else
            DoSimpleChecks = "Ready"
        End If
    End With

End Function

'@Ignore ProcedureNotUsed
Private Sub ClearOldDataButton_Click()
    Call ClearSheetDataForNewUse
End Sub

Private Sub ClearSheetDataForNewUse()

    With shData
        .Columns("A:E").ClearContents
        .Range("A1").Value = "Paste Tracking"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Paste Carton"
        '//Move the cursor here for the user to begin pasting here
        .Range("A2").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

**Form**: `ProgressIndicatorForm`

```
'@Folder("FedEx_Tracking")
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Call TopMost
End Sub
```

**Module**: `m_fedex_tracking`

```
Attribute VB_Name = "m_fedex_tracking"
'@Folder("FedEx_Tracking")
Option Explicit

Private Enum DataColumns
    [Paste Tracking] = 1                         'A
    [Paste Carton] = 2                           'B
    [Trimmed Tracking] = 3                       'C
    [Concat Links] = 4                           'D
End Enum

Private Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Public Sub TopMost()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Dim beginSeconds As Single
    beginSeconds = Timer()

    Call LudicrousMode(True)
    Call FormatColumnsAthruD
    Call TrimTextofTracking
    Call ConcatenateTrackingIntoLinks
    Call FilterForOnlyLinksAndPasteToSheetLinks
    Call LoopOpenIEandSelectAllCopyPaste
    Call SetEntireRangeOfResultingPastes
    Call CopyFilteredPastesToStatusesSheet
    Call CreateTableofStatuses
    Call CreateTableForTrackingCartonLookup
    Call IndexMatchToGetAssociatedCarton
    Call SetConditionalFormattingStatusColumnofStatusSheet
    Call FormatColumnWidthsOfStatusSheet
    Call FilterResultsOfStatusSheet
    Call TakeUserHereAtTheEnd

CleanExit:
    Call LudicrousMode(False)
    Unload ProgressIndicatorForm
    Dim endSeconds As Single
    endSeconds = Timer()
    MsgBox "Time taken to complete:" & vbNewLine & endSeconds - beginSeconds & " seconds", vbInformation, vbNullString
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume CleanExit

End Sub

Private Sub LudicrousMode(ByVal Toggle As Boolean)
    'Adjusts Excel settings for faster VBA processing
    'Code from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/c7nkgo/speed_up_vba_code_with_ludicrousmode/
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not Toggle
    Application.EnableEvents = Not Toggle
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Not Toggle
    Application.EnableAnimations = Not Toggle
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Toggle
    Application.Calculation = IIf(Toggle, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
End Sub

Private Sub FormatColumnsAthruD()

    Const HEADER_ROW_NUM As Long = 1
    '//Format columns A:C as text, not D, because I might want it to be a clickable link in the future
    shData.Columns("A:C").NumberFormat = "@"

    '//If there is old generated data, clear it
    shData.Columns("C:D").ClearContents

    'TODO: Take a look whether using private enum for columns is even necessary for this project scope with such few headers _
    it was mainly done this way because I had never used private enums before.

    '//Re-write the column headers of the cleared columns
    shData.Cells(HEADER_ROW_NUM, DataColumns.[Trimmed Tracking]).Value = "Trimmed Tracking"
    shData.Cells(HEADER_ROW_NUM, DataColumns.[Concat Links]).Value = "Concat Links"

End Sub

Private Function GetLastDataRow(ByVal xlSheet As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnLetter As String = "A") As Long
    'Function obtained from here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43290/importing-data-from-an-external-excel-sheet
    'RubberDuck inspection quacks: "Argument with incompatible object type" every time the function is used, but no errors are present when running the code.

    '//a worksheet's codename is passed to xlSheet;
    GetLastDataRow = xlSheet.Range(columnLetter & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End Function

Private Sub TrimTextofTracking()

    Dim lastPasteTrackingRow As Long
    lastPasteTrackingRow = GetLastDataRow(shData, "A")

    '//Use trim function to remove leading or trailing spaces, otherwise it will mess up lookups; _
    write to a new column
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastPasteTrackingRow
        With shData
            .Cells(i, DataColumns.[Trimmed Tracking]).Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Cells(i, DataColumns.[Paste Tracking]))
        End With
    Next i

    'shData.Columns(DataColumns.[Trimmed Tracking]).EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub

Private Sub ConcatenateTrackingIntoLinks()

    'Const OLD_PREFIX_FOR_FEDEX_LINK As String = "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/index.html?tracknumbers="
    Const PREFIX_FOR_FEDEX_LINK As String = "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber="
    Const SUFFIX_FOR_FEDEX_LINK As String = "&cntry_code=us&locale=en_US"

    '//This does not include the 1st tracking number at the start of each range. _
    If included, it would equal 30, which is the max number of tracking numbers that can be concatenated into a link, set by FedEx.com
    Const ADD_TO_FIRST_STRING As Long = 29

    '//First tracking number of link2 is 30 numbers after the first tracking number of link1
    'Link1inD2 = C2:C31
    'Link2inD32 = C32:C61
    Const ROWS_BETWEEN_GENERATED_LINKS = 30

    Dim lastTrimmedRow As Long
    lastTrimmedRow = GetLastDataRow(shData, "C")

    '//Ideally 30 Tracking numbers concatenated to form a link, then for example:& _
    tracking1-30 = link1; tracking 31-60 = link 2; etc.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastTrimmedRow Step ROWS_BETWEEN_GENERATED_LINKS
        shData.Cells(i, DataColumns.[Concat Links]).Value = PREFIX_FOR_FEDEX_LINK & _
                                                            concatRange(shData.Range("C" & i & ":C" & i + ADD_TO_FIRST_STRING), ",") & _
                                                            SUFFIX_FOR_FEDEX_LINK
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function concatRange(ByVal myRange As Range, ByVal mySeperator As String) As String
    'Code came from some website
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim currentRange As String
    Dim r As String

    currentRange = vbNullString

    For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            r = cell.Value & mySeperator
            currentRange = currentRange & r
        End If
    Next cell

    currentRange = Left$(currentRange, Len(currentRange) - Len(mySeperator))
    concatRange = currentRange

End Function

Private Sub FilterForOnlyLinksAndPasteToSheetLinks()

    shLinks.Cells.ClearContents

    '//Filter column, no blanks
    shData.Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    '//Get range & copy
    Dim lastConcatLinksRow As Long
    lastConcatLinksRow = GetLastDataRow(shData, "A")
    shData.Range("D2", "D" & lastConcatLinksRow).Copy

    '//Paste selection to new sheet
    shLinks.Range("C1").PasteSpecial

    '//Remove filter
    shData.Range("D1").AutoFilter

    '//Exit out of cut/copy mode
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Private Sub ClearAndFormatSheetPastesAsText()

    With shPastes
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub LoopOpenIEandSelectAllCopyPaste()

    Call ClearAndFormatSheetPastesAsText

    With shPastes
        '//Set the first place to begin pasting; This has to be here for the rest of the sub to work.
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

    Dim lastLinkRow As Long
    lastLinkRow = GetLastDataRow(shLinks, "C")

    Dim IEbrowser As Object
    Set IEbrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Dim linkRow As Long
    For linkRow = 1 To lastLinkRow

        With IEbrowser
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate (shLinks.Cells(linkRow, "C"))

            '//Wait for page to finish loading
            Do While .busy Or .READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                DoEvents
            Loop

            '//this additional wait is necessary on FedEx website to ensure page is fully loaded
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

            '// SelectAll (Ctrl+A)
            .ExecWB 17, 0
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            '// Copy selection (Ctrl+C)
            .ExecWB 12, 2
        End With

        '//Paste as Match destination formatting & _
        FormatHTML, but with no HTMLFormatting is absolutely necessary for pasting from FedEx tracking website & _
        because it keeps necessary table formatting. Tracking no., status, etc. are each kept in same row but separate columns, & _
        which makes it possible to filter the results. Pasting as text or values does not work!

        With shPastes
            .PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

            '//Set starting point for next paste
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        End With

        '//'https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html _
        if there are 10 links, it will show 10% complete after the 1st link
        Dim percentComplete As Single
        percentComplete = (linkRow / lastLinkRow) * 100
        progress percentComplete

    Next linkRow

    IEbrowser.Quit
    Set IEbrowser = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub SetEntireRangeOfResultingPastes()
    '//Find position of last cell
    Dim lastPastesRow As Long
    lastPastesRow = GetLastDataRow(shPastes, "A")
    'TODO: redo this particular lastColumn variable to get rid of ActiveCell
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).column

    '//Set range
    Dim EntireRangeOfPastes As Range
    Set EntireRangeOfPastes = shPastes.Range("A1", shPastes.Cells(lastPastesRow, lastColumn))

    '//Filter range on Column A ascending (A to Z), so the tracking numbers are at the top
    EntireRangeOfPastes.AutoFilter
    EntireRangeOfPastes.Sort key1:=shPastes.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    '//Remove duplicates on Column A
    shPastes.Range("A1", shPastes.Cells(lastPastesRow, lastColumn)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

End Sub

Private Sub CopyFilteredPastesToStatusesSheet()
    '//Find position of last cell
    Dim lastPastesRow As Long
    lastPastesRow = GetLastDataRow(shPastes, "A")
    'TODO: redo this particular lastColumn variable to get rid of ActiveCell
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).column

    '//Set range
    Dim filteredPastes As Range
    Set filteredPastes = shPastes.Range("A1", shPastes.Cells(lastPastesRow, lastColumn))

    '//Clear entire sheet, where I will be pasting to, along with clearing any conditional formatting
    With shStatus
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
        .Columns.Range("B:B", "B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
    End With

    '//Copy & Paste
    filteredPastes.Copy
    With shStatus
        .Range("B1").PasteSpecial
        .Range("A1").Value = "Carton"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CreateTableofStatuses()
    '//Since I have a lookup in column Z (column 26), & _
    Set this first table to have a max of 10 columns ending in column J, so there isn't a possiblity of a table overlap error
    Const FIRST_TABLE_LAST_COLUMN As Long = 10

    '//Get position of lastTrackingRow
    Dim lastTrackingRow As Long
    lastTrackingRow = GetLastDataRow(shStatus, "B")

    '//Create Table
    shStatus.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, shStatus.Range("A1", shStatus.Cells(lastTrackingRow, FIRST_TABLE_LAST_COLUMN)), , xlYes).Name = "tbl_FedEx"

    With shStatus
        '// Write/Overwrite Headers for first few columns in case there are no cartons with status found
        .Range("A1").Value = "Carton"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Tracking No. or Nickname"
        .Range("C1").Value = "Status"
        .Range("D1").Value = "Scheduled Delivery Date"
        .Range("E1").Value = "Ship Date"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CreateTableForTrackingCartonLookup()
    'Copying the range from shData to shStatus seems unnecessary, but if I want, I can make a copy of shStatus and rename it or move it to another workbook for historical and sharing purposes. _
    Sharing a single worksheet with all the info on it is easiest.

    '//Set range of first four columns
    Dim trackingCartonLookup As Range
    Set trackingCartonLookup = shData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    '//Copy & paste range far enough from the first table
    trackingCartonLookup.Copy
    shStatus.Range("Z1").PasteSpecial

    '//Find position of last cell in range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = shStatus.Range("Z1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = shStatus.Cells(1, shStatus.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

    '//Create Table
    shStatus.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, shStatus.Range("Z1", shStatus.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)), , xlYes).Name = "tbl_trackingCarton"

End Sub

Private Sub IndexMatchToGetAssociatedCarton()
    Const MINIMUM_TABLE_ROWS As Long = 2
    Const DOUBLE_QUOTE As String = """"
    '//To display a message upon N/A, replace vbNullString with "text" (including the " " around text)
    Const EXPLANATION_IF_NA As String = DOUBLE_QUOTE & vbNullString & DOUBLE_QUOTE

    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    With shStatus
        '//Index Match
        .Range("A2").Value = "=IFNA(INDEX(tbl_trackingCarton,MATCH([@[Tracking No. or Nickname]],tbl_trackingCarton[Trimmed Tracking],0),2)," & EXPLANATION_IF_NA & ")"

Continue:
        '//To prevent error, Autofill down--only if the table has enough rows
        If .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count > MINIMUM_TABLE_ROWS Then
            .Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("tbl_FedEx[Carton]")
        End If

    End With

    '@Ignore LineLabelNotUsed
CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Err.Clear
        '// Win 7 32-bit, Excel 2010 32-bit VBA 6.5 gave this error until I changed the formula to this
        shStatus.Range("A2").Value = "=INDEX(tbl_trackingCarton,MATCH(tbl_FedEx[[#This Row],[Tracking No. or Nickname]],tbl_trackingCarton[Trimmed Tracking],0),2)"
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    GoTo Continue

End Sub

Private Sub SetConditionalFormattingStatusColumnofStatusSheet()
    Const COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE As Long = 13561798  'Same as the Style "Good" fill color

    Dim statusColumn As Range
    Set statusColumn = shStatus.Range("tbl_FedEx[Status]")

    With statusColumn.FormatConditions.Add(xlTextString, TextOperator:=xlContains, String:="Picked Up")
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            .Color = COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE
        End With
    End With

    With statusColumn.FormatConditions.Add(xlTextString, TextOperator:=xlContains, String:="In transit")
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            .Color = COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE
        End With
    End With

    With statusColumn.FormatConditions.Add(xlTextString, TextOperator:=xlContains, String:="Delivered")
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            .Color = COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub FormatColumnWidthsOfStatusSheet()
    With shStatus
        '//Resize columns 'Carton', 'Tracking', & 'Status'
        .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 26
        .Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 26
        .Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 26
        '//Autofit 'Paste Tracking', 'Paste Carton', & 'Trimmed Tracking' columns
        .Range("Z:Z", "AB:AB").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub FilterResultsOfStatusSheet()
    Const COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE As Long = 13561798
    With shStatus
        '//Filter out the blanks in column 1 - disabled for now
        '.ListObjects("tbl_FedEx").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

        '//Filter on the green color
        .ListObjects("tbl_FedEx").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, criteria1:=COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TakeUserHereAtTheEnd()

    With shStatus
        '//Navigate the user here to view the results
        .Activate
        .Range("C1").Select
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub progress(ByVal percentComplete As Single)
    'Progress indicator code from here: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html
    ProgressIndicatorForm.Text.Caption = percentComplete & "% Completed"
    ProgressIndicatorForm.Bar.Width = percentComplete * 2

    DoEvents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stringly typed values. `DoSimpleChecks` can/should be typed as `Boolean` and renamed. Presently it's checking against a string value "Not Ready". It's also activating cells which means it's doing more than one thing. Rather than checking against a string have your function return a True/False value. Within that member you have a comment *'//Check if data has been pasted* which makes a fine name of `HasDataBeenPasted`. Refactor your code so that it does one thing and one thing only, checking whether data has been pasted.

```
Private Function HasDataBeenPasted() As Boolean
    HasDataBeenPasted = Not (shData.Range("A2").Value2 = vbNullString Or shData.Range("B2").Value2 = vbNullString)
End Function
```

The call site where that function invoked is updated to convert the implicit activation to an explicit activation that you can see. Now whoever maintains this code, be it your future-self or an axe wielding maniac that gets enraged at implicit things being done, won't have a surprise when they come back to this code months from now after forgetting there was an activation.

```
Private Sub StartTrackingButton_Click()
    If Not HasDataBeenPasted Then
        shData.Activate
        shData.Range("A2").Select
        MsgBox "Please paste in the following data:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "TRACKING number into A2" & vbNewLine & "CARTON number into B2", vbInformation, "Required Data"
    End If

    ProgressIndicatorForm.Show
End Sub
```

---

You have 3 conditional formats when you need only one. Comparing the target cell to each possible value and wrapping that in with the OR function does this. `=OR(C2="Picked Up",C2="In transit",C2="Delivered")` produces a True value for each of the values. Building up the logic to check these values leads to the code below. Now if you need to add or remove a value you can do so easily.

```
Private Sub SetConditionalFormattingStatusColumnofStatusSheet(ByVal interiorColor As Long)
    Dim targetArea As Range
    Set targetArea = shStatus.Range("tbl_FedEx[Status]")

    Dim prefix As String
    prefix = targetArea.Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False) & "="""
    Dim suffix As String
    suffix = ""","
    Dim comparisonsToStringValues As String
    comparisonsToStringValues = Join(Array("Picked Up", "In transit", "Delivered"), suffix & prefix)

    Dim builtFormula As String
    builtFormula = "=OR(" & prefix & comparisonsToStringValues & """)"

    With targetArea.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1:=builtFormula, TextOperator:=XlContainsOperator.xlContains)
        .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        .Interior.Color = interiorColor
    End With
End Sub
```

You also now supply the color. You had the color defined in 2 locations. Keep your code DRY as in Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY). As `FilterResultsOfStatusSheet` was called by the same procedure `TopMost` I moved the declaration of the Granny color const there and supplied it as an argument.

```
Public Sub TopMost()
    ...
    Const COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE As Long = 13561798  'Same as the Style "Good" fill color
    Call SetConditionalFormattingStatusColumnofStatusSheet(COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE)
    ....
    Call FilterResultsOfStatusSheet(COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE, False)
    ....
```

The signature of `FilterResultsOfStatusSheet` has changed too. Comments make it messy to enable/disable functionality, I prefer refactoring to have an argument to toggle it on or off. Also note that instead of having `shStatus.ListObjects("tbl_FedEx").Range` twice it's been consolidated to a single variable which is used. Another example of keeping your code DRY.

```
Private Sub FilterResultsOfStatusSheet(ByVal interiorColor As Long, ByVal filterOutBlanks As Boolean)
    Dim tableArea As Range
    Set tableArea = shStatus.ListObjects("tbl_FedEx").Range

    If filterOutBlanks Then
        tableArea.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    End If

    tableArea.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=interiorColor, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
End Sub
```

---

There is no need to format column widths individually in `FormatColumnWidthsOfStatusSheet`. Change them all at once with `.Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth = 26` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things from a quick scan. I'm sure someone will do a much more thorough review "soon". (Remember, it can take quite a while to do a thorough code review, be patient!)

1. Eliminate `Call`, it's obsolete and not needed for your purposes.
2. `FormatColumnsAthruD` is very explicit - almost too explicit. What if you ever need to use column `E`? Will you rename your procedure? Also, in it you have hard coded `"A:C"`, yet you have a nice `Enum` defining handy names for those columns, which you ignore.
3. You actually ignore your `DataColumns` enum all over the place, instead using magic letters whose values could change in the future.
4. You late bind `IEbrowser` robbing you of Intellisense help while programming.
5. In `IndexMatchToGetAssociatedCarton`, you end the error handling with `Goto Continue`. That should be `Resume Continue`. A) with `Goto Continue`, VBA remains in "error handling" mode - new errors will get you a standard VBA error box that will bubble all the way up to your main procedure and abort all processing, and B) I think you'd be hard pressed to find any legitimate use for `GoTo` in "modern" (i.e. less than 30 years old) VBA code usage *other* than in an `On Error Goto x` statement.
6. You have `Const COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE As Long = 13561798` which is great since you're eliminating a magic number. However, what if your boss decides he wants that color to be "Kelly green" instead of "Granny Apple green"? Are you going to rename the `Const` as well as giving it a new value? Why not just call it `COLOR_SUCCESS` instead? #NamingIsHard (but #RenamingIsEasyWithRubberduck)
7. On the topic of Granny Apple green, I see it defined in at least 2 places. If you're going to use globals (and for `Const`, it's not horribly egregious though a settings class might not be a bad idea), this would be a good one to add there. Your output would look really funny with some "Granny Apple" green and some "Kelly" green because you didn't find both definitions of the `Const`.
8. Actually, I see `Const COLOR_GRANNY_APPLE As Long = 13561798  'Same as the Style "Good" fill color`. Since it's the `'Same as the Style "Good" fill color`,  why not just use the "Good" style fill color instead of defining your own `Const` for this?

---

```
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Err.Clear
        '// Win 7 32-bit, Excel 2010 32-bit VBA 6.5 gave this error until I changed the formula to this
        shStatus.Range("A2").Value = "=INDEX(tbl_trackingCarton,MATCH(tbl_FedEx[[#This Row],[Tracking No. or Nickname]],tbl_trackingCarton[Trimmed Tracking],0),2)"
    Else
```

Instead of letting this fail and retrying if you're on a 32-bit version of Office, why not:

```
    With shStatus
        #If VBA7
          .Range("A2").Value = "=IFNA(INDEX(tbl_trackingCarton,MATCH([@[Tracking No. or Nickname]],tbl_trackingCarton[Trimmed Tracking],0),2)," & EXPLANATION_IF_NA & ")"
        #ELSE
          shStatus.Range("A2").Value = "=INDEX(tbl_trackingCarton,MATCH(tbl_FedEx[[#This Row],[Tracking No. or Nickname]],tbl_trackingCarton[Trimmed Tracking],0),2)"
        #ENDIF
```

Which will only execute the appropriate version of the code based on what version the host is running in.

---

You have:

```
'@Ignore LineLabelNotUsed
CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
```

The fact that Rubberduck is flagging `CleanExit:` as an unused line label is telling you something that you shouldn't be ignoring!

`IndexMatchToGetAssociatedCarton` has `CleanExit:` followed immediately by `Exit Sub`, however, in your error handler, you also have an `Exit Sub`. You should replace that with `Resume CleanExit`. While having a single exit point from every procedure isn't critical, it does, generally make life easier, especially if you're not writing really contorted code to do so.